# XPath to select second row of table isn't working for Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a table on a web page with 3 rows and 3 columns. I'm trying to iterate over the rows, but Selenium selects only the first table row although I'm indexing the rows from 1 to 3.

I'm selecting first the table, then using it's context I'm selecting the row, finally using it's context I'm selecting the input field.

Here is the foundBy info of the web element:

`[[[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (2299dfcfe1d9176b6184ef9afa04e150)] -> xpath:` 
`//div[contains(@class,'Table') and @data-viewid='table']//table]] -> xpath: tbody/tr[2]]] -> xpath:`
`//div[contains(@class,'Text') and @data-viewid='text2']//div[contains(@class, 'input')]/input]`

No matter which index I'm using after tr, it works always in the first row. It drives me crazy.

Any help appreciated. What's wrong?

Thx,
Laszlo

Comment: Can you share DOM details or URL for further check?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the specific xpath and go directly to it or if you have a unique value on the table in each row, you can loop through the table and then do what you please on the row.

example:
let's say you have a table:

```
|color | email    |car| edit|
|red   |no@no.com |bmw |button|
|blue  |no1@no.com|audi|button|
|yellow|no2@no.com|ford|button|
```

So let's say we want to find out what car the user drives and then click on the button for him to edit his details.

call the method and pass the email address -

```
  ClickTableLink("no1@no.com");
```

In the below, tds[i] is the email address field because that is the variable we are passing and that is where we stop. Now we are on the correct row sitting on the email address. But we want to find the car the user drives and then edit the data. If tds[i] is our email field, we need to increment 1 or tds[i+1] to get to the car field and increment 2 or tds[i+2] to click the button. If we wanted the color, we need to subtract 1 or tds[i-1] and then get the value of the color they like.

```
 public void ClickTableLink(string value)
 {
 var table =  driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='MyTable']"));
 foreach (var tr in table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")))
 {
 var tds = tr.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
for (var i = 0; i < tds.Count; i++)
 {
 if (tds[i].Text.Trim().Contains(value)) 
 {
     var car = tds[i+1].Text;
     tds[i + 2].Click();
    break;
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dazed, but it do not solves the problem. I need the xpaths mentioned in the question to get working well.